# Specifying Constructor Arg for GenericKeyed Pool( Apache Commons)

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, apache-commons

I am trying to inject values using spring config: but i am getting this error

```
Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

The Spring code snippet is:

```
<bean id="Pool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool">
        <constructor-arg name = "factory" ref="xyzFactory" />
        <constructor-arg type = "int" name = "maxActive" value='3' />
        <constructor-arg type= "byte" name = "whenExhaustedAction" value='WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW' />       
        <constructor-arg type = "long" name = "maxWait" value='3000' />
        <constructor-arg type = "int" name = "maxIdle" value='3' />
        <constructor-arg name = "testOnBorrow" value='true' />
        <constructor-arg name = "testOnReturn" value='true' />
    </bean>
```

Please Advice?

Answer (score 1):

With this

```
<constructor-arg type= "byte" name = "whenExhaustedAction" value='WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW' />
```

Spring will try to convert the `String` value `"WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"` to a `byte` and fail.

You should be able to use [`<util:constant>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-constant)

```
<constructor-arg type= "byte" name = "whenExhaustedAction" />     
    <util:constant static-field="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</constructor-arg>
```

To resolve the value of the `static` field. Don't forget to add the corresponding namespace to your xml context.

---

Please be consistent and use double quotes on your attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW is that a byte value? Doesnt look like it, maybe that needs to be a referenced bean or something

```
<constructor-arg name = "testOnBorrow" value='true' />
<constructor-arg name = "testOnReturn" value='true' />
```

Add the `type=boolean` to these

And check xyz factory correctly implements `KeyedPoolableObjectFactory`

Comment: `WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW` is a static constant of the class, see [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool.html).

Comment: Still throwing the same. I have a feeling the issue is with byte option. dont know how to test it. please advice